# PRONOUND PLUS 'TO +VERB" OR "PREPOSITION +VERB-ING

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction, verbs, infinitive-vs-gerund

I know it this sentence is wrong but i need an explanation.

RIGHT : I hope you would help me in letting him understand.
WRONG:  I hope you would help me to let him understand.

RIGHT: Adults should support them in deciding their future careers.
WRONG: Adults should support them to decide their future careers.

i hope someone can help me

Comment: You are incorrect in your assumption about the first two. There is nothing wrong with _help me to [verb]_. I can't 'explain' why we say _help someone to do something_ but _support them in doing something_ - it's just how the language works.

Comment: A problem with this question is that even the so-called "right" answer doesn't look right, so it's difficult to proceed further.   We don't often "let people understand". Rather, choose a form of the word "explain" instead.  We don't often "support people in deciding".  Perhaps the word "assist" would work. Or, after the fact, "support them in their decision".